# Using Tensorflow model between languages [JS -> Python]

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, is it possible to use a model generated by lets say TensorflowJS into a Python flow?

Comment: yes it is possible using the tensorflowjs converter. You can have a look at the docs here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!